# Convert message object to string (Gmail api and python)

Tags: python, gmail-api, tostring

I am trying to save only a specific part of an email using python. I have the variables service, userId and msg_id but I don't know how to convert the variable plainText to a string in order to take the part that I want in the get_info function

```
def get_message(service, user_id, msg_id):
    try:
        #get the message in raw format
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
        
        #encode the message in ASCII format
        msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode("ASCII")).decode("ASCII")
        #put it in an email object
        mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
        #get the plain and html text from the payload
        plainText, htmlText = mime_msg.get_payload()
            
        print(get_info(plainText, "start", "finish"))
    except Exception as error:
        print('An error occurred in the get_message function: %s' % error)

def get_info(plainText, start, end):    
    
    usefullText = plainText.split(start)[2]
    usefullText = usefullText.split(end)[0]
    return usefullText
```

after running the code I have the following error message:

An error occurred in the get_message function: 'Message' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I cannot find from where is function `email.message_from_string(msg_str)`, but most probably `mime_msg.get_payload()` won't retrieve plainText but object Message

Comment: I have added these 2 imports:
import email
import base64

Comment: you can check `print( type(plainText) )` to see what type of object you have - and then you can find documentation and read more about its methods and attributes. And you can also use  `print( dir(plainText) )` to see what methods has this object - maybe there is `plainText.text` or `plainText.body` or something similar to get raw text from message. You can also try `help(plainText)`. If you use some `IDE` (like `PyCharm`) then you can try `plainText.` (with dot at the end) and press probably Ctrl+Space to get information about methods in this object.

Comment: if it is [email Message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) then in documentation you can see it has `as_string()`, `get_body()`, etc. It has also `__str__()` so you can use `str(plainText)` but this probably can gives you string with all elements  - headers, body, attachements.

Comment: try `plainText.get_content()` to get message's body as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The method `get_payload()` doesn't exist for the [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) class. You need to use `as_string()` instead.*

#### Code Fix:

The code inside your `try` block needs to be updated, from:

```
#get the plain and html text from the payload
plainText, htmlText = mime_msg.get_payload()
```

to:

```
#get the plain and html text from the payload
plainText, htmlText = mime_msg.as_string()
```

#### References:

- [`email.message`: Representing an email message — Python 3.8.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html)

  - [`as_string()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.as_string)
- [`email.parser`: Parsing email messages — Python 3.8.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html)

  - [`message_from_string()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string)